# Largest subgraph with each couple of vertices connected by one edge

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I'm quite a newbie in graph theory so I don't know if there's a name for such a subgraph, and thus I do not find much information about this.

Say you have the following undirected graph :

[image: graph]

I'm looking for the right algorithm for finding the largest subgraph in which each vertex is linked with any other vertex by a path of exactly one edge.

So in this example, it would be the subgraph 4, 5, 6. The subgraph 7,8 also works but is smaller, and the subgraph 0,1,2,3 doesn't work since 0 and 2 are not linked by one edge.

If your code could be written in either javascript or python, I'd appreciate it ! But pseudo-code would be fine too.

Comment: You want to find the [maximum clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). The problem is NP-hard so you will have to settle for an approximate algorithm for non-toy graphs.

Comment: @SaiBot Thanks a lot for the term. Finding information will be much easier now.

Comment: Do you mean "linked with *every* other vertex"?  In that case, @SaiBot is right.  Otherwise, just delete all vertices with no neighbour.